# Make Python 2D masked array similar to MATLAB's

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matlab

I'm currently working in translating a MATLAB script to python. There is a step on the MATLAB code where I need to select entries from a matrix (2D array) based on a boolean matrix with the same dimensions. When I tried to write the equivalent code in Python I noticed that the elements in the resulting array were in a different order compared to the MATLAB. More precisely, MATLAB seems to select the elements in column-wise order, and Python in row-wise order. Is there a way to make Python output the array in MATLAB order?

Tiny example:

MATLAB:

```matlab
a = [1, 2, 3; 4, 5, 6; 7, 8, 9];
b = [false, false, true; false, false, false; true, false, false];
a(b) % outputs [7;3] or [a(3,1); a(1,3)]
```

PYTHON:

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]))
b= np.array([[False, False, True], [False, False, False], [True, False, False]]))
a[b] # outputs array([3,7]) or array([a[0,2], a[2,0])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on the answer of Mikhail Genkin, one could use

```
a.T[b.T]
```

(`a.T[b]` gives the same result in this particular case since `b` is a symmetric matrix). Another option is

```
a.flatten('F')[b.flatten('F')]
```

Comment: Thanks! Just for completion: a.T[b.T] is way faster than a.flatten('F')[b.flatten('F').

Comment: Yes, transposition creates a view, while flattening returns a copy, so it is slower.

Answer (score 1):

How about transposing the array `a` in Python first?

```
 a.T[b]
```

Comment: Thanks, I just had to made the fix proposed for @bb1 because the real matrix I'm working  is not squared

Comment: Right, my answer doesn't generalize for a non-symmetric mask matrices

Answer (score 0):

If we flatten the MATLAB matrices:

```
>> a(:)
ans =

   1
   4
   7
   2
   5
   8
   3
   6
   9

>> b(:)
ans =

  0
  0
  1
  0
  0
  0
  1
  0
  0
```

the selection becomes more obvious.

```
>> a(b)
ans =

   7
   3
```

`a.T` reorders the `numpy` array, so does the use of order 'F' (which is what matlab uses)

```
In [112]: a=np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3,order='F')
In [113]: a
Out[113]: 
array([[1, 4, 7],
       [2, 5, 8],
       [3, 6, 9]])
In [114]: a[b]
Out[114]: array([7, 3])
```

`numpy` default is 'C' order; the last dimension changes fast.  When converting between the two we need to keep that order difference in mind.

Or look at the order of elements when the transpose is raveled:

```
In [126]: a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
In [127]: a
Out[127]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
In [128]: a.T.ravel()
Out[128]: array([1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9])
```